# How do I mutably use an instance from multiple instances on the stack in Rust?

Tags: design-patterns, rust

I am relatively new to Rust, coming from mainly C++ and Python trying to learn how to do things the rust way.  The following code uses unsafe code to be able to use an instance of A mutably from instances of both B and C.  I don't think I should need to use unsafe code to do this, but I could be wrong.  Is there a better way without using dynamically allocated memory, and without flattening B and C into the same implementation?

```
use core::cell::UnsafeCell;

struct A {}

impl A {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        // does something
    }
}

struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a UnsafeCell<A>,
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn do_something_with_a(&mut self) {
        unsafe { (*self.a.get()).do_something() }
    }
}

struct C<'a> {
    a: &'a UnsafeCell<A>,
    b1: B<'a>,
    b2: B<'a>,
}

impl<'a> C<'a> {
    fn new(a: &'a UnsafeCell<A>) -> Self {
        Self {
            a: a,
            b1: B{a: a},
            b2: B{a: a},
        }
    }

    fn use_b(&mut self) {
        self.b1.do_something_with_a();
        self.b2.do_something_with_a();
    }

    fn use_a(&mut self) {
        unsafe { (*self.a.get()).do_something() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = UnsafeCell::new(A{});
    let mut c = C::new(&a);
    c.use_b();
    c.use_a();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to hit the book: [section 15.5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) explains all you need to know about achieving interior mutability without `unsafe`.

Comment: Adding to what  @E_net4isadownvote said, there's also a fantastic in-depth video by Jon Gjengset on `Cell` and `RefCell`: [Crust of Rust: Smart Pointers and Interior Mutability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O0Nt9qY_vo).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to this problem from the comments.

```
use core::cell::RefCell;

struct A {}

impl A {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        // does something
    }
}

struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a RefCell<A>,
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn do_something_with_a(&mut self) {
        self.a.borrow_mut().do_something()
    }
}

struct C<'a> {
    a: &'a RefCell<A>,
    b1: B<'a>,
    b2: B<'a>,
}

impl<'a> C<'a> {
    fn new(a: &'a RefCell<A>) -> Self {
        Self {
            a: a,
            b1: B{a: a},
            b2: B{a: a},
        }
    }

    fn use_b(&mut self) {
        self.b1.do_something_with_a();
        self.b2.do_something_with_a();
    }

    fn use_a(&mut self) {
        self.a.borrow_mut().do_something()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = RefCell::new(A{});
    let mut c = C::new(&a);
    c.use_b();
    c.use_a();
}
```